# Trying to link to specfic new comic review page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get a link on an articles show page so that when a user clicks write new review it takes them to the link

```
/comic_reviews/'the article they want to comment on'/reviews/new
```

where they will be directed to the new reviews page

how can i accomplish this with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your routes file you would specify a route like this

`match '/comic_reviews/:comic_name/reviews/new' => 'reviews#new', via: :get`

Then in your reviews controller you would need something like this

**reviews_controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @comic = Commic.find_by_name(params[:comic_name])
    if @comic
      @review = @comic.reviews.build
      render 'new'
    else
      #Render some error page since comic was not found
    end
  end
end
```

You will then have access to `@comic` and `@review` in your `reviews/new` view so you could build a form that just makes a post to create a review and allows you to store it. This should get you going.

**Edit**

In your `new` view you'd need to have a form that looks something like this

```
<%= form_for @review do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :some_attribute %>:
  <%= f.text_field :some_attribute %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will be expecting you have a route to create a review in your routes file and an action in your ReviewsController.

If you are struggling with such topics I suggest you read over this excellent tutorial

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Or just read through the documentation for Rails API which will give you pretty accurate examples.

Comment: so what would i do in my views?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via routes

```
resources :comic_reviews do
  resources :reviews
    #probably_some_other_route_here
end
```

And with restful pattern it will be easy to achieve whatever you want

controller

```
Someclass < Someotherclass

  #some your code

  def new
    @instance_var = Your_model.new
  end

  def create
    @instance_var = Your_model.new(params[:some_name_here])
    if @instance_var.save
      redirect_to somewhere
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Also you'll need form, but i dont think that will cause any troubles